# Mysql table is adding rows itself

Tags: php, mysql

Short Story: I wrote a code in a loop that insert rows into mysql table, and kept it running for 3 hours accidentally.  I tried to empty the mysql table, but then again it automatically starts to insert rows. I even tried to drop and re-create it, but it is automatically inserting rows (`id` in increasing order)

Full story:

2 days ago, I wrote a code that use an API and insert the data into mysql table (in a loop). And to mesure, how many records I have added, I made an table named "`lastrequestdone`" and started to insert the `id` number after every record inserted successfully.

But the code inserted all the ID's in 1 hour, and after that, the API started to give error:404 response, and the loop started to run very fast.

So assume that, I ran a loop for 3 hours, that insert an `id` in increasing order. But once i realized it, I stopped the loop. Tried to empty the table, but whenever I empty the table, more rows automatically starts to get inserted.

Then i dropped the table, and created it again today, but the same thing is happening. Rows are getting inserted automatically.

Comment: Try to kill the associated process

Comment: something is still running in the background then. Either you didn't kill it properly or it got restarted somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for the processes in your `MySQL` Server using any UI tools like `MySQL Workbench` or likes of it and try to find the process of the query that you left running and stop that particular process. You should probably resolve it this way.

Answer (score 1):

Hope it might help you - https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/63302/how-to-stop-the-execution-of-a-long-running-insert-query

Do you mean by "kill / stop the MySQL instance" the linux command kill -9 ...?
Yes, this might lead to corrupt data.

Which instead should not leave corrupt data is the [build-in kill command](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/kill.html) of MySQL. See the lower part of the page, which states that it might take the thread some time to actually notice the presence of the kill flag. The part which states it does not roll back updates when transactions are not used (which implies that it rolls back updates if transactions are used), etc. I therefore assume this does not corrupt any data (besides killing repair and optimize as noted there).

You can find out the thread id you need for this command with [the command show processlist.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-processlist.html)