# how install mailso librrary https://github.com/detochko/MailSo to yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

it's my composer.json file. It is possible to do by composer?

```
{
"name": "yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced",
"description": "Yii 2 Advanced Project Template",
"keywords": ["yii2", "framework", "advanced", "project template"],
"homepage": "http://www.yiiframework.com/",
"type": "project",
"license": "BSD-3-Clause",
"support": {
    "issues": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues?state=open",
    "forum": "http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/",
    "wiki": "http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/",
    "irc": "irc://irc.freenode.net/yii",
    "source": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2"
},
"minimum-stability": "stable",
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.4.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2": "~2.0.6",
    "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "~2.0.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "~2.0.0",
    "zxbodya/yii2-gallery-manager": "*@dev",
    "yiisoft/yii2-redis": "^2.0",
    "ssilence/php-imap-client": "dev-master",
    "ddeboer/imap": "^1.2"
},
"require-dev": {
    "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "~2.0.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2-gii": "~2.0.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2-faker": "~2.0.0",

    "codeception/base": "^2.2.3",
    "codeception/verify": "~0.3.1"
},
"config": {
    "process-timeout": 1800,
    "fxp-asset":{
        "installer-paths": {
            "npm-asset-library": "vendor/npm",
            "bower-asset-library": "vendor/bower"
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can.

Add this line in your `composer.json` under `require`:

```
"intelogie/mailso":"~0.7.9"
```

Comment: when use "composer update" i have problem: - The requested package detochko/mailso could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name

Comment: You need to `composer install` first.

Comment: thank you very much! "intelogie/mailso":"dev-master" real installed paccage to my application

Comment: Okay. Accept and upvote the answer if it has been resolved.

Comment: how i can do this?

Comment: The way upvoted and accepted on this answer. You see green tick?
 That is to accept answer and click `^` arrow to upvote. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48620165/1485183

Comment: this is the most pathetic side of the **`stackoverflow users`** who are here to get an answer and then dont even bother to award the person who helped solve the problem by just selecting the answer as correct @d.y , anyhow i am upvoting this answer as it solved the OP's problem although he didnt bothered to read the link and upvote for the person who helped him out, such people should be left alone to solve their own problems by themselves

Comment: I want accept and upvote the answer but I need  15 reputation to mark an answer correct. If I am wrong, please show me how I can do this